# How can I make my cells in UITableView editable?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have 2 view controllers. One is a UITableView and the other is the VC that lets me add a cell in the table.

PeopleListViewController:

```
var people = [Person]()
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return people.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = (people[indexPath.row]).dateTime //Each row will say the date of the person.
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){

    }

    @IBAction func done(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
        var addPersonVC = segue.sourceViewController as AddPersonViewController

        var newPerson = Person()
        newPerson.dateTime = addPersonVC.date

        people.append(newPerson)
    }
```

AddPersonViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateAndTime: UITextField!
    let date = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dateAndTime.text = "\(date)"
    }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "doneSegue" {

        }
    }
```

Right now what it does is comes up with a tableview. When I click the add button it takes me to the addpersonvc and automatically preloads the date. When I hit done, it goes back to the peoplelistvc and fills the date in the table cell.

How can I make it so that when I click on a cell it will let me go back to the addpersonvc and edit it?
Thank you.

Comment: "How can I make my cells in UITableView edible?" I think you mean editable. UITableViewCells aren't THAT delicious..

Comment: So, you want to show `AddPersonViewController` when you tap on a cell (which has date on it), and present the view controller with pre-filled date?

Comment: The AddPersonViewController will have more fields such as first name, last name, etc. When you click on a cell it should pull the information from that person

Answer (score 1):

One way is you can create your own custom cell. Create a custom cell class, with a .xib file. Register the NIB in your viewController. Then you can use your custom cell, editable in the .xib file.

If you register the custom cell in your view controller, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath tableview function, you can declare your cell as

```
var nib : UINib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
table.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")

var cell: customCell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCell
```

I read your question better. This is how you edit the visual appearance of your cell. My bad.

You need to implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

Nates on the right track. There are two ways to do this.

1. Programatically:

To do this programatically implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and then instantiate a new controller. You can then use the indexPath variable to get the index from the data array that your table is consuming.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var vc : UIViewController! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("practice") as UIViewController
}
```

2. Using Storyboards

If you want to do this using storyboards, create a viewController and a tableViewController. Than right drag from one of your table view cells, to the viewController object. A popup menu will appear, and choose "Show", this will create a segue that will let you go to that view when you select one of the cells. You'll then have to write the code to populate it in the UIViewController